# The "Activity" tab severely messed up on iOS 9.3.5

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, safari

So... uh... just look at this:

[image]

I don't even know what to say here. The Reputation box is *a mess*: it's impossible to even see how much rep I have, or how it changed over time, because the part with the Python gold badge and the one with the rep changes overlap. The same thing happens with the Badges box.

iPad 3rd gen running Safari in iOS 9.3.5. Would be nice to see this fixed.

Comment: A lot of design is messed up actually ... the last release seems very buggy

Comment: Safari 12 came out recently; since [Stack Overflow supports the last two versions of the major browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/194720) does that mean Safari 9 is no longer supported?

Comment: I confirm: I've been seeing this for a couple of days, now. iOs 10.3.3