# CSS bugs on Safari desktop

Tags: bug, design

I have noticed the following strange CSS bugs on the profile page of my Stack Overflow account lately:

[image]

This is happening on my desktop Safari (I use a MacBook Air).  I can't say anything about mobile Safari.  I can confirm that this problem does not exist on Chrome desktop/mobile.

Thank you.

Comment: No repro. Safari 12.0 (13606.2.11). MacOS 10.13.6

Comment: What version of Safari are you running, Tim?

Comment: `Version 10.1.1 (12603.2.4)`

Comment: Okay...I'm gonna go out on a limb and say since that version [isn't supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history), you're not going to likely make much headway on this one.

Comment: @Makoto I guess I should stop closing those irritating upgrade warning I keep getting prompted with :-)

Comment: Ignoring an update prompt for 2 years; Now that's dedication :p

Comment: @Turnip:  I mean, Windows XP was easy to simply not upgrade...at this point it's in one's DNA. :P

Comment: Before I delete this, I'll leave it up, just in case the boys did some recent CSS changes which might have caused other issues, perhaps on browser versions which should still be supported.  Obviously, some changes were made recently.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374707/the-activity-tab-severely-messed-up-on-ios-9-3-5

Comment: I confirm seeing exactly this in Safari on iPad. As a matter of fact, I was just about to post here, myself...

Comment: @CindyMeister iOS version?

Comment: Version 10.3.3.

Comment: Safari 10.1.1 was released in May of 2017, it's now October of 2018. The browser is just over a year old, surely it should still be supported?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/369403), only the last 2 major releases are supported (Safari 11 and 12), but mobile Safari should be supported for iOS 9+

Comment: @damd See [Sanity check with browser support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313867/369403). For Firefox, if you're a couple of months behind you're no longer supported

Comment: Also ensure you’re not hitting the browser cache and that files are loading properly. In the browser, type Shift+F5, or hold shift and click the refresh button.  In iOS may need to be restored. Not sure there’s a reset for app cache. If iOS SO uses safari you can try clearing safari cache